# Why can't Object.runtimeType be used in an as expression?

Tags: dart

According to the Dart docs for [Object.runtimeType](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-core/Object/runtimeType.html), the field's type is `Type`. Which is confusing because I get an error from the compiler complaining about this field not being a type.

See this sample code:

```
final double first = 1.0;
final int second = 2;

final third = second as double;       // works fine, unlike declaration below.
assert(first.runtimeType == double);  // true

final fourth = second as first.runtimeType;
```

The last line throws this compile-time error:

> The name 'first.runtimeType' isn't a type, so it can't be used in an 'as' expression.

The sample code shows that `first.runtimeType == double`, so wouldn't it follow that `_ as first.runtimeType` is equivalent to `_ as double`?

Comment: **Moderator Note** - Please [be nice](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) in the comment section.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is simple actually, `runtimeType` is only available at RunTime and cannot be statically analyzed by the compiler.